# How to convert string to htmluri?

Tags: c#, .net, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf

I use Haukcode.WkHtmlToPdfDotNet is a wrapper for WkHtmlToPdf. I need to add a footer to each page from html string like:

```html
<div>
    <table border="1" width="100%" style="
        border: 5px solid royalblue;
        border-spacing: 0;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        text-align: center; 
    ">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: normal; margin: 0; line-height: 1.1em; color: royalblue;">
                    Organization: "INFORMATICA" LLC.</br>
                    Date of signing: 05.03.2023 15:49:32</br>
                    Name: Daria Valeryevna Ivanova</br>
                    Position: Leading Specialist</br>
                    Certificate ID: 2DCEFE0001AD0CAA411A1D6CB228DCD6</br>
                    Signature validity date: 17.02.2025 10:13:52</br>
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

However, the footer object takes an HtmlUri as content. Have any idea how to convert it.

**EXAMPLE:**

```
            var converter = new SynchronizedConverter(new PdfTools());

            FooterSettings footer = new FooterSettings()
            {
                HtmlUrl = "https://myfooter.com"
            };

            var doc = new HtmlToPdfDocument()
            {
                GlobalSettings = {
                    ColorMode = ColorMode.Color,
                    Orientation = Orientation.Landscape,
                    PaperSize = PaperKind.A4
                },
                Objects = {
                    new ObjectSettings() {
                        PagesCount = true,
                        HtmlContent = transformedContent,
                        WebSettings = { DefaultEncoding = Encoding.UTF8.HeaderName },
                        HeaderSettings = { FontSize = 9, Right = "", Line = false, Spacing = 2.812 },
                        FooterSettings = footer
                    }
                }
            };

            try
            {
                byte[] pdf = converter.Convert(doc);
                Helpers.FileHelper.SaveData(documentInfo.FileName, pdf);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
                throw;
            }
```

I have only one way to create a method on my own controller which will return the page and pass to the property htmlUri a reference to the controller method which will return a piece of html code. But perhaps there is an easier way?